# ProductListing based on Attribute in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I would like to show "Suggestions" in my product listing in Magento. I made an attribute "Suggestion" which is Yes/No and global active. Now in the listing I would like to show the suggestions first, then some text and stuff, and then the rest of products.

I tried it like this:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()
/* .... */
$_productCollection->clear()->addAttributeToFilter('suggestion', 1)->load();
```

But this ends in an exception:

> You cannot define a correlation name '_price_rule' more than once

Now the question is, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution for me was a custom module, which extends the List Functionality. I added the following file:

> /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php

With the following extending code:

```
protected function _getProductCollectionSuggestion()
{
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
    if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
        $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
    }

    // if this is a product view page
    if (Mage::registry('product')) {
        // get collection of categories this product is associated with
        $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
            ->setPage(1, 1)
            ->load();
        // if the product is associated with any category
        if ($categories->count()) {
            // show products from this category
            $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
        }
    }

    $origCategory = null;
    if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
        if ($category->getId()) {
            $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
        }
    }
    $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
    $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('suggestion', 1);
    if($this->_productCollection->count()) {
        foreach($this->_productCollection as $_productKey => $_product) {
            if($_product->getSuggestion() == 0 || !$_product->getSuggestion()) {

            }
        }
    }

    $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

    if ($origCategory) {
        $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Then I loaded this method in the List.phtml and it worked :)
Thanks for reading anyway! Maybe this code helps someone!